# Loading big files into GtkSourceView is slow

Tags: pygtk, gtksourceview

I am trying to load 1k+ lines long files into GtkSourceView, using GTK3 in Python (PyGObject).

Whenever I set the text, it takes 2-3sec to fully appear (it is slowly scrolling and adding new lines at the bottom). I have connected a profiler and it shows 99.5% of cpu time in Gtk.main.

Basically I am using this for setting text:

```
txt_sourceview.get_buffer().set_text(new_text)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: I am using the c language. I have also encountered this problem!